# Convert Checkboxes into dropdown list on Googleform

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Good day,

I have a Google form questionaire with 120+ questions on it, and all its choices are the same and on checkbox, Is there a way to convert the checkbox into dropdown? This ways it will be cleaner and easier to choose using tab.

I am currently doing it manually but theres alot of other questionnaires with the same problem.

thanks a lot and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's fairly easy. Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)? You simply have to utilize the `FormApp` and use `FormAp.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)` to get all items that are a list. Then all you need to do is iterate over that list and do the following:

1. Get the current item as a `LIST` item (all items will by of `ITEM`
   type)
2. Create a new `CHECKBOX` item
3. Copy title from old item to new item
4. Copy help text from old item to new item
5. Copy required from old item to new item
6. Copy choices from old item to new item
7. Get indexes of both old and new items
8. Move new item to old item index
9. Delete old item

Though I am against giving code and would preffer you write it yourself, it's so trivial that I might as well just give it to you:

**EDIT: I misread the question and thought the goal is to change dropdown to checkbox, instead of checkbox to dropdown. Editing the code to reflect the reverse goal**

To adjust the code yourself, you really need to only change a few lines. `var itemList = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)` change as per the [enum ItemType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type) and change the `oldItem` and `newItem` to `as` and `add` with the respective types.

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()  
  var itemList = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)
  var oldItem, newItem, oldIndex, i

  for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    oldItem = itemList[i].asCheckboxItem()                      //get the item as a checkbox item to gain access to the choices
    newItem = form.addListItem()                                //create a new list item (you can use any other type)        
    newItem.setTitle(oldItem.getTitle())                        //copy the title
    newItem.setHelpText(oldItem.getHelpText())                  //copy the help text
    newItem.setRequired(oldItem.isRequired())                   //copy if it is required
    newItem.setChoices(oldItem.getChoices())                    //copy the choices
    oldIndex = oldItem.getIndex()                               //get where the current item is    
    form.moveItem(form.getItemById(newItem.getId()), oldIndex)  //move the new item to the old items position

//    -----Another optional way to move the item----
//    var newIndex = newItem.getIndex()
//    form.moveItem(form.getItemById(newIndex, oldIndex)
//    -----------------------------------------------    

    form.deleteItem(itemList[i])                                //delete the old item
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time sir @Vytautas but code above gives the opposite result instead of converting checkbox into dropdown items, what it does converts dropdown items into check boxes. Ill try to understand the code and give it a try :D

Comment: @melvnberd sorry, must have misread. It's rather easy to reverse. It's a simple change really. Do try it yourself, but I will amend the answer